# AudioKit stop and start produce weird sounds

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

i have 2 issues regarding the weird sounds in audiokit. let me explain it to you.

my app has a framework that is using audio permissions. for playing and recording already.

i tried 3 things.
1st approach. i have added a new feature using the audio-kit. when i start the audio-kit for the first time its perfectly working. but when i go to other screen and give permission to other framework the other framework works fine but when i came back to audio-kit the volume is too low. it seems to be cut by 50% and i cannot boost it back to 100%.

to bypass this i thought i have to stop the audio-kit and start it again when i have to use it. but weird stuff happened.

2nd approach. if i stop the audio kit to before using other-framework and comeback to audio-kit and restart it again, it creates weird buzzing sounds on playing sound and on stopping sound.

3rd approach. i used a sample code from "MetronomeSamplerSync". i used a sample code for metronome app. and on play i start the audio-kit and on stop i stop the audio-kit. and if produces the same issue of weird sound.

here is the sample code.

```
func startStopAction(met: AKSamplerMetronome, otherMet: AKSamplerMetronome) -> (AKButton) -> Void {
        return { button in
            // Stop if playing, Start if not playing.
            if met.isPlaying {

                met.stop()

                do {
                    try AudioKit.stop()
                } catch {
                    AKLog("AudioKit did not stop!")
                }
            } else {
                //If other metronome is playing, sync to it, else just play.
                if otherMet.isPlaying {
                    let now = AVAudioTime(hostTime: mach_absolute_time())
                    let beatAtNow = otherMet.beatTime(at: now)
                    met.setBeatTime(beatAtNow, at: now)
                } else {
                    do {
                        try AudioKit.start()
                    } catch {
                        AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
                    }
                    met.play()
                }
            }
            button.title = met.isPlaying ? "Stop" : "Play"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very hard to help without sample code, preferably a clone-able buildable project.

Comment: This is not really an answer, so I'll put it here as a comment.  Why are you starting and stopping AudioKit?  Isn't sufficient to start and stop things inside AudioKit? Its not going to be performant for your app to constantly go through the tear down and build up process.

Comment: i am starting an stoping the audiokit again because my other framework is based on superpowered SDK which also another framework for audio and when it starts the audiokit sound is reduced by 50%

Comment: @AureliusProchazka any help here?

Comment: I don't use Superpowered and I don't know who is stopping on whose toes to create this issue.  I asked in my first comment if you could provide a project for me to check this out with.

Comment: hello @AureliusProchazka sorry but i cant share the code. i signed the NDA. you said its not a good idea to start and stop the AudioKit everytime. but the problem is if i don't start and stop the volume is reduced to 50%. but when i start and stop the audiokit again and again the sound get weird. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was having the weird sound issue. and i fixed the issue by assigning the audio files again to metronome. there was no weird sound anymore and no more volume cut down. hope it will help all.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue (audiokit-volume cut by 50%). I had to remove the following lines in my other code:

```
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        // Configure the audio session for movie playback
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback,
                                mode: AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement,
                                options: [])
```

My guess is that the session categories have to be set very carefully and best would be if your other framework and AudioKit use the same AVAudioSession set up only once. Hope this helps.